# How can I sync calendars and contacts across platforms while *not* using a related email address?

Tags: email, sync, android, calendar, ios

Okay, this one is super complicated, but I'll try my best to be clear and concise.

I am trying to help a user get his accounts together. The user has the following hardware:

- iPad
- Android phone
- Windows PC at his workplace (Has Outlook)
- Mac computer at his house

His line of work is somewhat private, so he's using a 'secure' email method through a third-party using IMAP.

Now on to the actual question: How can I sync his contacts and calendars across all of these devices?

Any ideas/apps/services y'all have some good experiences with? I know nothing of iCloud, but I heard that may be a solution. I'm not sure how that would work with the Android device though.

Any apps or services recommended don't need to be free! It would be great, but not necessary.

Comment: afaik, there's no way to use iCloud to sync with non-Apple setups - PCs work, as they have iCloud control panel, but not Android. iCloud can manually download sets of vCards, but that would require manual merge.

Comment: There are actually several apps that can pull this off, but I was wondering if there were any 'best practices' that anyone had found really worked for them, even if they were particularly convoluted first-party solutions.
Example of such apps [can be found here.](http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/synchronization/keep-android-and-ios-in-sync-part1-data-email-contacts-and-calendar/)